# Phalcon 1.2.6: $dispatcher->getControllerName() not returning a string?

Tags: php, phalcon

**The Situation:**

I have two environments: my local dev machine (Dev), and my production server with Media Temple (Prod). I've installed Phalcon on both. Dev seems to be successfully running a very basic (1 controller) Phalcon site. However, Prod is having issues with the same code.

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to convert non-camelcased controllers and actions to valid camelcased ones (e.g. "test-page" to "testPage"). This is working on Dev but not Prod. The error I'm receiving on Prod is:

```
Warning: Invalid arguments supplied for camelize()
```

Using the following code ([full gist](https://gist.github.com/ryanwalters/9002906)):

```
$eventsManager->attach('dispatch', function ($event, $dispatcher) {
      $controllerName = Phalcon\Text::camelize($dispatcher->getControllerName()); // Throwing an error here...
      $dispatcher->setControllerName($controllerName);

      $actionName = Phalcon\Text::camelize($dispatcher->getActionName()); // ... and here
      $dispatcher->setActionName($actionName);
});
```

Looking at https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/ext/kernel/string.c#L225 it looks like the camelize() function returns this error when the value is not a string.

**The Question(s):**

So this would mean that $dispatcher->getControllerName() is not returning a string?

Why would this be happening? What would cause this function return different types?

**Server Info:**

```
DEV:  Apache 2.2.22 / PHP 5.3.13 Win7
PROD: Apache 2.2.22 / PHP 5.3.27 Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

it's strange, that it does not return string. it should :/

try this:

```
$controllerName = Phalcon\Text::camelize((string) $dispatcher->getControllerName()); //
```

also try dumping what's happening there:

```
var_dump($dispatcher->getControllerName());
```

if it returns null/false or some other stuff, you can simply redirect user to some place with:

```
$this->view->disable(); // for flash messages to keep in session (if you use some)
$this->response->redirect($this->url->get("user/index"), true); // true for external redirect
return; // stop doing anything
```

maybe you have done some wrong things with your router? Have done anything with it? there are ways to define current controller..

you can try this:

```
$paths = $this->router->getMatchedRoute()->getPaths();
var_dump($paths);
```

also in your router you can try to add this:

```
$router->add('/:controller[/]{0,1}', array(
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 'index'
));
```

or with action:

```
$router->add('/:controller/:action[/]{0,1}', array(
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
));
```

Comment: I casted `getControllerName()` to `(string)`, which makes the error go away, but then no controller gets loaded at all. Only the base layout is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be reacting to `dispatch:beforeDispatch` event, not to all `dispatch` events.

The very first event is sent by the dispatcher is `dispatch:beforeDispatchLoop` and according to the [documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/dispatching.html#dispatch-loop-events), this event is…

> Triggered before entering in the dispatch loop. At this point the
>   dispatcher don’t know if the controller or the actions to be executed
>   exist. The Dispatcher only knows the information passed by the Router

Thus if the router has not find an exact match for the URL (this is not an error, as the default settings will be applied later), the controller name will be `null`.

Comment: There is no error, but the content still does not load using `dispatch:beforeDispatch` on Prod. This works on Dev, however (but so did the original `dispatch` listener).

Comment: Then please show the code :-)

And/Or compare `$event->getType()` on dev and production.

Comment: The gist is linked in the question, https://gist.github.com/ryanwalters/9002906. Trying to `var_dump($event->getType())` from within the `dispatch` listener shows nothing on either Dev or Prod. Where should I place that in order to see a result?

Comment: Right before `$controllerName = Phalcon\Text::camelize($dispatcher->getControllerName());`

Comment: I can't seem to get `var_dump()` to show anything when placed inside the `attach()` method in Dev or Prod.